# bloco HTML dentro de Variável JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código JS:

```
success: function (result) {
if (result[0] == "Erro") {
    $(".dadosAdmin").html( result[1] );
} else {
    dadosAdmin = "
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Nome</label> : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Apelido</label> : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>dataNascimento</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Telefone</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Celular</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Bairro</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Endereço</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Email</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Sexo</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Estado Cívil</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Data Batismo</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Bloqueado</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Batizado Fora?</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>usuario</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
        <label class='labelPequeno'>Senha</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>                        
        ";

    $(".dadosAdmin").html(dadosAdmin)
 }
```

Mas está dando erro na linha:

```
dadosAdmin = "
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Na verdade preciso fazer algo como:

```
$(".dadosAdmin").html( "
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Nome</label> : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Apelido</label> : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>dataNascimento</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Telefone</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Celular</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Bairro</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Endereço</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Email</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Sexo</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Estado Cívil</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Data Batismo</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Bloqueado</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Batizado Fora?</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>usuario</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>
    <label class='labelPequeno'>Senha</label>  : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>    "       
);
```

Porém já dá erro na primeira linha.

Obs.: SIM, uso jQuery em outras partes desse arquivo

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado

```
html  = "<label class='labelPequeno'>Nome</label> : " + result[1]['nome'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Apelido</label> : " + result[1]['apelido'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Nascimento</label>  : " + result[1]['dataNascimento'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Telefone</label>  : " + result[1]['telefone'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Celular</label>  : " + result[1]['celular'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Bairro</label>  : " + result[1]['bairro'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Endereço</label>  : " + result[1]['endereco'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Email</label>  : " + result[1]['email'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Sexo</label>  : " + result[1]['sexo'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Estado Cívil</label>  : " + result[1]['estadoCivil'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Data Batismo</label>  : " + result[1]['dataBatismo'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Bloqueado</label>  : " + result[1]['bloqueado'] + " <br/>";
html += "<label class='labelPequeno'>Batizado Fora?</label>  : " + result[1]['batizadoFora'] + " <br/>";

$(".dadosAdmin").html( html );
```